# Associative array manipulation struggles

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m trying to make sense of what’s happening in the following code:

```
var dataset = [
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Nokia", target: "Apple", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "HTC", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Barnes & Noble", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Foxconn", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Oracle", target: "Google", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "HTC", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Inventec", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Samsung", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "LG", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "RIM", target: "Kodak", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Sony", target: "LG", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "LG", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Huawei", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Ericsson", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "Samsung", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "Samsung", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "RIM", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit"}
];

var nodes = {};
update(dataset);

function update(links){
    var i = 1;
    links.forEach(function(link){
        // Pre iteration checks
        console.log(i);
        console.log(link.source);
        console.log(nodes[link.source]);
        // Observations – initial dataset is being overwritten? 

        // Should the following be read as “if one evaluates to true, do both?”
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, linkCount:0}); // Initialize new nodes with zero links
        link.source.linkCount++;

        // Post iteration checks
        console.log(link.source);
        console.log(nodes[link.source]); // This is undefined if link.source is now an object. This is effectively saying console.log(nodes[object])
        console.log(nodes[link.source.name]); // This now says console.log(nodes["Microsoft"]) (for ex)
        i++;
    });
}
```

If I write down what I think is happening in each iteration, I see the following:

- Iteration 1: `"Microsoft" = nodes["Microsoft"]`? False.
- So set `nodes["Microsoft"] = { name: "Microsoft", linkCount: 0 }`
- Increment underlying nodes `linkCount + 1` so `nodes["Microsoft"] = { name:
  "Microsoft", linkCount: 1 }`

---

- Iteration 2: `"Microsoft" = nodes["Microsoft?"]`? True.
- Increment underlying nodes `linkCount + 1` so `nodes["Microsoft"] = { name: "Microsoft", linkCount: 2 }`

---

- Iteration 3: `"Samsung" = nodes["Samsung"]`? False.
- So set `nodes["Samsung"] = { name: "Samsung", linkCount: 0 }`
- Incremement underlying nodes `linkCount + 1` so `nodes["Samsung"] = { name: "Samsung", linkeCount: 1 }`

---

I suspect my confusion has something to do with how the OR (`||`) operator is working. My thinking is that if the LHS evaluates to false, skip it and do the RHS. Is this wrong?

EDIT:

If I look at just the first iteration;

```
dataset[0].source = nodes[dataset[0].source] || (nodes[dataset[0].source] = { name: dataset[0].source })
```

We want BOTH sides to happen. dataset[0].source should be set to nodes[dataset[0].source] AND we want to set the 'value' for nodes[dataset[0].source].

If I try to run both like this;

```
dataset[0].source = nodes[dataset[0].source];
nodes[dataset[0].source] = { name: dataset[0].source };
```

then the first line runs fine, presumably swapping out "Microsoft" for a pointer to nodes["Microsoft"] (undefined currently) but then trying to update nodes["Microsoft"]'s name with the dataset[0].source value, which is undefined, only sets nodes["microsoft"]'s name value to undefined.

If I try the code like this;

```
dataset[0].source = nodes[dataset[0].source] || nodes[dataset[0].source] = { name: dataset[0].source };
```

Then I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" - not sure why that's the case?

Finally if I try

```
dataset[0].source = nodes[dataset[0].source] || (nodes[dataset[0].source] = { name: dataset[0].source });
```

with added parentheses around the RHS, all works as it should. dataset[0].source is the object and nodes[dataset[0].source] is also the object.

Why this behaviour occurs for these three different code structures is ultimately what I don't understand and specifically why the third one works

Comment: Why is there no semicolon after `var nodes = {}` and some of the other `console.log()` lines?

Comment: semicolons are optional in JavaScript

Comment: But after `var` there’s also the option of a comma which means something different. It would be _far less confusing_ with semicolons.

Comment: I don't see how that would be confusing. If next line begins with a comma it would be very clear that it's supposed to continue the previous line. the only confusing case for semicolon insertion is when a line begins with a `(` as that can be a legitimate first character, but also tries to call the previous line's value as a function.

Comment: Can we not get hung up on semicolons pls. I want to understand how source of the underlying dataset is being overwritten and the string replaced with an object. I don't see anywhere in the code that's making that happen (if you work through my iteration assumptions the underlying data isn't being affected)

Answer (score 0):

The  [binary logical operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11) `||` is also called the "default" operator. It does not generally return a boolean, but instead returns the first value unless it is falsy, and the second value in that case. In other words,

`a || b`

literally returns *a* or *b*.

e.g. `null || 4`  returns 4.

And yes, the right-hand-side expression is completely ignored (parsed but not evaluated) if the left-hand-side is true.

As for `link.source`, by attempting to assign a property to that string, the code is implicitly *boxing* the string into an object. Both strings and numbers can be boxed in that way, either to use inherited methods and properties (e.g. `link.source.length` to get the length of the string) or to assign them new ones. They retain their type by doing so, unlike what happens if you did `new String(link.source)`: that creates a true object that behaves like one in every respect.

Comment: That's what I thought. So if you look at my Iteration assumptions, are they correct? It's the "Increment underlying nodes..." part that's entrenched in what I'm not understanding - link.source is now apparently an object that we can increment the linkCount property of when I don't see where we're manipulating link.source from a string value into an object?

Comment: Actually logical operators don't return "true" or "false" but the result of the comparison. So `'bar' || 'foo'` doesn't evaluate to true but "bar" which is a truthy value. `'bar' && 'foo'` isn't "true" neither but result in "foo" (which is also a truthy value).

Comment: @hwilson1 I hope I understood your question about turning link.source into an object. Edited my answer.

Comment: @Touffy thanks for the edit - I'm not sure I know what boxing is but having googled it looks like something to do with providing a pointer to the object? Which makes perfect sense. It's HOW that pointer gets in to the source part of my dataset that I'm struggling with. On the first iteration: "Microsoft" = nodes["Microsoft"] || nodes["Microsoft"] = {name: "Microsoft", linkCount: 0 }. What's actually happening here? Neither side is an equality operator, they're both assignment operators so how can there be a true/false relationship between them (the ||?)

Comment: The assignment operator (`=`) doesn't just do the assignment, it also returns the assigned value so the whole expression `(a=b)` has the value of `b`. Note the parentheses in the actual code, which are necessary because `=` has lower priority than `||`.

Comment: Ahh just as x*y + a*b would process as (x*y) + (a*b) and you're forced to use parentheses if what you wanted was x * (y + a) * b?

Comment: Yes. If you did `a = b || c = d` without parens it would evaluate `b || c` first, then try to assign `d` to the result and to `a`.

Comment: Or rather that's if you only consider operator priority. `b || c` isn't a valid left-hand-side expression so it actually throws a SyntaxError before it even gets a chance to run. If you trick the parser into running the code anyway, it will completely evaluate `b || c` and then throw a ReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure where the confusion is, but the code is working in this way:

```
var dataset = [ /*data*/]
var nodes = {}

update(dataset);
```

This is, as expected, initialising your array with large amounts of data and nodes as an empty object literal, then calls your update function.

-

```
function update(links) {
    var i = 1;
    links.forEach(function(link)
    {
        //content
        i++;
    });
}
```

This is iterating over your array, incrementing the value of i.

Two slightly tangential points here - rather than incrementing i yourself, the callback passed into foreach takes index as its second argument; and be careful using forEach if supporting older browsers as it doesn't work with pre-IE8 browsers.

```
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, linkCount:0});    // initialize new nodes with zero links
link.source.linkCount++;
```

This is the crux of your loop code.The lazy "OR" operator works exactly as you mentioned - if the left-hand side is truthy then it doesn't evaluate the first part, so

```
true || foo();
```

will never evaluate the "foo" function. So, if nodes[link.source] does exist (and is truthy, but defined objects are always truthy) then it ignores the second part and assigns that value to link.source, overwriting the existing data set.

If the expression on the left hand side is falsey, then it will evaluate your right-hand side and create the node in nodes and assign it to link.source.

This means that at the end of the code being run, nodes will an object with properties containing linkCounts and names; and data-set will be the same array, but with the source property of each object relaced by the same linkCount/name objects.

-

I'm not entirely sure how you want your code to work, so am not sure where this deviates from your expected running.

One thing that may be an issue is you discuss comparing link.source and nodes[link.source], but that doesn't happen in the code you've written because you're using single equals ("=") the assignment operator, rather than double or triple equals ("==" or "===") which are the comparative operators? If you wanted that, then the relevant line would read :

```
(link.source == nodes[link.source]) || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, linkCount:0});
```

I'd be wary about using the or operator in this trick-sy way, as clever code can often be hard to read down the road, and if that's what you're going for, I'd favour a standard if statement for greater readability:

```
if(link.source !== nodes[link.source]) {
    nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, linkCount:0}
}
```

However, if that is what you want, then it gives you a bizarre and meaningless output... =\

Comment: Immeasurably helpful. I'm ultimately working towards producing a d3 force layout and I need this raw data into nodes and links; nodes being a list of distinct companies and links defining their relationships. 

I follow exactly what you've said, but in the first iteration following that logic the LHS evaluates to false as there's no nodes["Microsoft"], so even though the nodes["microsoft"] is added to the nodes array, how can we then increment link.source.linkCount when link.source is still holding a string value? 

Would you be so kind as to go through the first few iterations for clarity?

Comment: Incidentally if I swap the || structure for your if structure I get a different set of results in console.log. So I don't think that's exactly what the || structure is doing.